# Multiple sets of const names with scope in Go

Tags: go

I have a Go application that requires an unbounded number of sets of constants. The application also requires that I be able to map strings to (integer) consts, and vice versa at runtime. The names of the constants are guaranteed only to be valid identifiers, so it's a near certainty that there will be duplicate const names. In particular, each set of constants has an element called "Invalid". In C++11, I'd use enum classes to achieve scope. In Python, I'd probably use class variables. I'm struggling to find an idiomatic way to express this in Go. Options that I've looked at include:

- Using a separate package for every set of consts. This has lots of disadvantages, because I'd rather the whole set be in the same package so that I can build support for these sets at the package level, and so that I can test the whole lot without overly complicating the test code to do multi-package testing at once.

`first.go`:

```
package first
type First int
const (
    ConstOne First = iota
    ConstTwo
    Invalid = -1
)

func IntToCode(fi First)string { ... }
func CodeToInt(code string)First { ... }
```

`second.go`:

```
package second
type Second int
const (
    ConstOne Second = iota
    ConstTwo
    Invalid = -1
)

func IntToCode(se Second)string { ... }
func CodeToInt(code string)Second { ... }
```

`example.go`:

```
import (
    "first"
    "second"
)

First fi = first.CodeToInt("ConstOne")
Second se = second.Invalid
```

- Using the tried-and-true technique of a globally unique prefix for each const. Given, though, that the number of sets is really big, having to essentially invent and manage a bunch of namespaces using a coding convention is awkward at best. This option also forces me to modify the names of the consts (which is the whole point of using them).

`first.go`:

```
package mypackage

type First int

const (
    FI_CONSTONE First = iota
    FI_CONSTTWO
    FI_INVALID = -1
)

func IntToCode(fi First)string { ... }
func CodeToInt(code string)First { ... }
```

`second.go`:

```
package mypackage

type Second int

const (
    SE_CONSTONE Second = iota
    SE_CONSTTWO
    SE_INVALID = -1
)

func IntToCode(se Second)string { ... }
func CodeToInt(code string)Second { ... }
```

`example.go`:

```
package mypackage

import (
    "first"
    "second"
)

First fi = first.CodeToInt("ConstOne")
Second se = SE_INVALID
```

What's a better, more idiomatic solution? I'd love to be able to say things like:

```
First fi = First.Invalid
```

but I haven't been successful in coming up with an approach that allows this.

Comment: The only way that "first" can be in scope in mypackage is if it's imported as a package called first or defined in the mypackage package. So if you have your heart set on first.Invalid then you either need to have a first package or define first as a struct in mypackage.

Comment: You _could_ nest all your const packages within a super package and run the tests on that one. What is the use case though?

Comment: Is picking a unique prefix for each group of constants that big a dea?  If you were using C++11 enum classes, you'd also need to come up with names for each of those classes.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious: use `First_Invalid` instead of `First.Invalid`?

Comment: @voutasaurus The use case is an implementation of HL7 FHIR in Go. The XML Schema definition has about 100 simple types with enums that are most naturally implemented as consts in Go. Because instances of the classes built on top of these enums need to be parsed from both XML and JSON, I need to recognize them as strings as well

 How would that nesting work? It sounds promising.

Comment: From what I've just read all codes in HL7 FHIR come with namespaces. So it's probably worth matching that here in some fashion. For nesting it's worth considering making two interfaces, one containing a method `Code() string` and another containing `Val() int` and then making first.Code and first.Val types with methods matching those interfaces (Code for Val and Val for Code). Then in the super package where you define the interface type you can write functions manipulating objects of Coder and Valer type, in particular testing functions.

Comment: @voutasaurus Would you care to put some of these thoughts into an answer, so that I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have separate packages for your separate code sets and a single package for defining the higher level functionality associated with codes and write tests for that higher level package.

I haven't compiled or tested any of this:

E.g. for a code set:

```
package product // or whatever namespace is associated with the codeset

type Const int

const (
    ONE Const = iota
    TWO
    ...
    INVALID = -1
)

func (c Const) Code() string {
    return intToCode(int(c)) // internal implementation
}

type Code string

const (
     STR_ONE Code = "ONE"
     ...
)

func (c Code) Const() int {
    return codeToInt(string(c)) // internal implementation
}
```

E.g. for the higher level functions package:

```
// codes.go
package codes

type Coder interface{
    Code() string
}

type Conster interface{
    Const() int
}

func DoSomething(c Coder) string {
    return "The code is: " + c.Code()
}    

// codes_product_test.go
package codes

import "product"

func TestProductCodes(t *testing.T) {
    got := DoSomething(product.ONE) // you can pass a product.Const as a Coder
    want := "The code is: ONE"
    if got != want {
        t.Error("got:", got, "want:", want)
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

To retrieve the const for a particular code you could do something like

```
product.Code("STRCODE").Const()
```

Maybe it's better if `Const()` returns a `Coder` so that `product.Code("ONE").Const()` can be a `product.Const`. I think if you play around with it there are a few options and there will be a good one in there somewhere.